# Programmatically/generically retrieving enum values from db4o

Tags: c#, db4o

I am trying to get information out of an offline copy of a db4o database.  I do not have the original object classes, as these are from a Java app (and I am working in C#), so I have built myself a wrapper in LINQPad, using db4o's GenericObjects, and can query it nicely enough for most objects.

However, I am having trouble querying enum values, as they report not to have any fields.  However, when I view them in the Object Manager Enterprise add-in for Visual Studio, I can see the stored enums in a name/ordinal fashion, but the stored IDs there don't seem to match the IDs I have retrieved from the GenericObject (so I can't marry them up manually).

*(inb4 anyone asks why I don't just use OME, the drag/drop query builder in OME is, let's say, less-than-useful, hence the LINQPad route.)*

I can't imagine the Visual Studio plugin *not* using a similar GenericObject approach to querying the database, so can anyone demonstrate how I might derive the enum name from the GenericObject I have retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

I found it; the enum name/ordinal are stored under the base 'table' for `java.lang.Enum`.  They have the same stored ID as they do in the named enum 'table'.

The following seems to work:

```
var myEnumObjectID = db.Ext().GetID(myEnumObj);
var enumNameField = db.Ext().StoredClass("java.lang.Enum").StoredField("name", null);
var myEnumName = enumNameField.Get(db.Ext().GetByID(myEnumObjectID));
```

*(Now to see if I can do something similar for collections!!)*